# Sub-pixel shift estimation of a moving object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

With a stationary webcam, I am taking sequential pictures of an object that is being displaced in each frame.  I am trying to estimate the sub-pixel shift of each frame but the estimates are way off. Since the estimates where wrong in my first trial, I created a mask for the object and tried to estimate the shift with just the moving object while removing the background.  But the estimates of the pixel shift were the same.

```
function delta_est = estimate_shift(s,n)
h = waitbar(0, 'Shift Estimation');
set(h, 'Name', 'Please wait...');

nr = length(s);
delta_est=zeros(nr,2);
p = [n n] % only the central (aliasing-free) part of NxN pixels is used for shift estimation
p(1)

sz = size(s{1});
S1 = fftshift(fft2(s{1})); % Fourier transform of the reference image
for i=2:nr
  waitbar(i/nr, h, 'Shift Estimation');
  S2 = fftshift(fft2(s{i})); % Fourier transform of the image to be registered
  S2(S2==0)=1e-10;
  Q = S1./S2;
  A = angle(Q); % phase difference between the two images

  % determine the central part of the frequency spectrum to be used
  beginy = floor(sz(1)/2)-p(1)+1;
  endy = floor(sz(1)/2)+p(1)+1;
  beginx = floor(sz(2)/2)-p(2)+1;
  endx = floor(sz(2)/2)+p(2)+1;

  % compute x and y coordinates of the pixels
  x = ones(endy-beginy+1,1)*[beginx:endx];
  x = x(:);
  y = [beginy:endy]'*ones(1,endx-beginx+1);
  y = y(:);
  v = A(beginy:endy,beginx:endx);
  v = v(:);

  % compute the least squares solution for the slopes of the phase difference plane
  M_A = [x y ones(length(x),1)];
  r = M_A\v;
  delta_est(i,:) = -[r(2) r(1)].*sz/2/pi;
end

close(h);
```

What changes do I need to make to get the shift to the right sub-pixel estimation?

[image: Target Object][image: Shifted Object]

Comment: Do you really expect good measurements from those crappy images ? [Sorry for informality.]

Comment: given the low SNR, I would expect the position to be fluctuating with a standard deviation larger than a pixel, making subpixel estimation illusory.

Comment: Just because your program gives you many digits doesn't mean that you really have that accuracy. given the small features any temporal noise or even the Bayer interpolation will kill any sub-pixel accuracy. how repeatable is the position or in your case phase values for 30 shots without any movement?

Comment: it won't kill it alone, but it will certainly not make things better. and it is a difference if you calculate an average shift across the entire sensor or if you track one feature. let's say you have a green spot, then the red pixels won't contribute much useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vision.PointTracker` in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. It can track points across frames with sub-pixel accuracy.

Comment: vision.PointTracker looks like it is for R2016b. My version is R2012b.  However, I do have opencv for matlab and will try with opencv.

Comment: Actually, it was introduced in R2012b, so you should have it if you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox. Otherwise, try `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` from OpenCV.

Comment: I am getting the best result with this method.  Since the background is not changing, I am wondering if I could use a high resolution image of the background, for background modeling to obtain a more accurate motion estimation with optical flow?

Comment: If you do background modeling, then you don't need optical flow.  Try `vision.ForegroundDetector` in matlab.